# How to check whether your work on WP or WPMU?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpmu

I use global variable `$table_prefix` to differ whether I work on Word Press or WPMU. I need this global variable for my plugin. But is there any better way to check whether your pluggin is working on Word Press or WPMU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPMU a global variable named `wpmu_version` should be set.

Comment: yes, that's it. i should use isset rather then compare its table_prefix. i'm too focus with it's return value. As you know, in wp, they got $wp_version as global variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

for my checks I use a function I found

```
// from http://frumph.net/wordpress/wordpress-plugin-theme-check-for-multisitewpmu/
        // check for multisite. Returns boolean
        function check_this_is_multsite() {
            global $wpmu_version;
            if (function_exists('is_multisite')){
                if (is_multisite()) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!empty($wpmu_version)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

use it like this

```
if(check_this_is_multsite()){
    // is on wpmu
} else {
    // is on single
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a constant:

e.g.

`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'WP');`

`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'WPMU');`

Comment: wow this is a good suggestion. But what if i'm a pluggin developer. i need to know it without able to access/read wp-config.php (i think my question misleed you)